# Format this data as XML or JSON with Python

Tags: python, xml, json, soap

I have a SOAP web service that I am posting a request to with Python, but I am not sure how to format the return.

**UPDATE**: Return is an 'instance' being returned by SUDS

I have been able to return just one record of the 40, which is included below:

```
print len(xmloutput)
print len(xmloutput[1].ODI_Outage)
print xmloutput[1].ODI_Outage[6]
```

This is the return that I am getting:

```
2
40
(ODI_Outage){
   metersAffected = 28
   ERT = 
      (ert_time){
     ert = "2013-07-19T20:50:00Z"
  }
 Incident = 
  (incident){
     Location = 
        (location){
           mainAddress = 
              (mailaddress){
                 townDetail = 
                    (towninfo){
                       code = "L7L6W3"
                       name = "BURLINGTON"
                       stateOrProvince = "ONTARIO"
                    }
              }
           PositionPoints = 
              (coordinates){
                 xPosition = -79.7833492971
                 yPosition = 43.3923166879
              }
        }
    }
 }
```

How do I take this return and create either XML or JSON for all of the ODI_Outage objects?  Just not sure what to do.

Comment: What kind of object is the response? Is it a `str`? Or is this simply the printed representation.

Comment: returns an 'instance'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the type of the return use: `print type(your_return_variable)`